# PHP pagination loses variable on other pages- whats the solution?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP pagination loses variable on other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638999/php-pagination-loses-variable-on-other-pages)

I am having the exact same issue that another member had. This issue was brought up by another member, Tatty27, and solved. The correct script however was not shown. Any ideas?

[PHP pagination loses variable on other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638999/php-pagination-loses-variable-on-other-pages)

Comment: I quote: The recommendation is to use `session_start()` at the top of your scripts, in all pages, and use `$_SESSION['variable']=`... to store variables. This way, they will persist across pages.

Comment: Your question will most likely be closed, OP, but what is unclear about the solution offered in the duplicate question? You can persist data by using $_SESSION. Read this article: http://phpmaster.com/php-sessions/